# c++ must take exactly one argument

Tags: c++, forms, c++11

I'm a new c++ learner.Now,I have a problem in my code, but I don't know how to debug it. Please help me. It's `form.h`  file.
I try to  move val and operator<< into Form.

```
class Form{
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Form&);
int prc;
int fmt;
double val;
public:
explicit Form(int p=6):prc(p){
  fmt = 0;
  wdt = 0;
}
Form& scientific(){
 fmt = ios_base::scientific;
 return *this;
 }
Form& precision(int p){
 prc = p;
 return *this;
}
Form& fill(char);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Form& bf){
  ostringstream s;
  s.precision(bf.prc);
  s.setf(static_cast<ios_base::fmtflags>(bf.fmt), ios_base::floatfield);
  s.setf(bf.fmt,ios_base::floatfield);

  s << bf.val;
 return os << s.str() ;
 }
};
```

This is my main.cpp:

```
Form gen4(4); // general format, precision is 4
void f(double d)
{
  Form sci8 = gen4;
  sci8.scientific().precision(8);
  Form fix8 = gen4;
  fix8.fixed().precision(8); 
  cout << d << sci8(d) << fix8(d) << d;
 }
```

When I compile, it says:

```
error: ‘std::ostream& Form::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Form&)’ must take 
exactly one argument

error: no match for call to ‘(Form) (double&)’
<< "gen4 = " << gen4(d) << endl
```

Comment: Please copy the error message into the question instead of linking an image.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, especially as links that can disappear. Instead copy-paste the text, in full and without editing, into the question body. Especially errors. Please edit your question to include the error output as text.

Comment: sorry for that. I had post the error message into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
// vvvvvv
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Form& bf)
// ^^^^^^
    {
      ostringstream s;
      // ...
```

implementing the operator.

If you forget the `friend` keyword inside the boby of the class, `operator<< (std::ostream &, Form const &)` is intended as a member of `Form`, the argument on the left of `<<` is implicitly the `Form` object and both declared arguments are intended on the right.

Comment: It's the same result as before.T_T
Actually,I had done it before , but it  does't work.

Comment: @L.MH - the error `no match for call to ‘(Form) (double&)’ << "gen4 = " << gen4(d) << endl` show that `friend` isn't used (`Form` is on the left); you should show us a full example to reproduce the error; not only the class definition.

Comment: @L.MH - maybe my answer isn't clear: you have to add `friend` in the definition of the function; not (only) in declaration; answer modified to explain better.

Comment: I have put a full example.
If you know how to  solve , i appreciation so much!

Comment: @L.MH - No; isn't a full example. Lack of `main()` and there are discrepancies in your `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

**error: ‘std::ostream& Form::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Form&)’ must take 
exactly one argument**

Here are two ways to define Friend Function:

Inside the class:

```
class Form
{
    friend ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Form& bf)
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```

Outside the class:

```
class Form        
{
    friend ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Form& bf);
};


ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Form& bf)
{
    //do something
}
```

**error: no match for call to ‘(Form) (double&)’
<< "gen4 = " << gen4(d) << endl**

Use operator overloading, something like this

```
class Form
{
    double operator()(double i)
    {
        //do something
    }
};
```

Comment: May I ask for more clear about no match for call to ‘(Form) (double&)’ << "gen4 = " << gen4(d) << endl.
Override() operator
I don't understand how it work.